# Android App Errors out when trying to access wireless

Tags: android, wireless, android-wifi, android-networking

I'm coding an Android app and I want to make sure the wireless is connected before I invoke the browser to show a stream, however it Simply closes when the button is clicked saying that the application has stopped running. I have set the permission in the android manifest file. Here is my code. In a separate class called Networking I do this.

```
public class Networking extends Main {

    public boolean  isWirelessConnected()
    {
        cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); 
    NetworkInfo mwifi = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    if(mwifi == null)
        return false;
    else 
        return true;
    }
    public void messageDialog()
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder alrtBuild = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alrtBuild
        .setTitle("Wireless")
        .setMessage("You are not Connected would you like to Connect to wireless?")
        .setNegativeButton("Yes", new  DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                WifiManager wifiManger = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                wifiManger.setWifiEnabled(true);

            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();

            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = alrtBuild.create();
        alert.show();


    }
}
```

And in the main class I have

```
Networking netwrk = new Networking();
if(netwrk.wireless().isConnected())
{
    Intent brwoserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
             Uri.parse("http://www.own3d.tv/HotshotGG"));
    startActivity(brwoserIntent);               
}
```

Here Is the errors the program throws when I hit the button

```
12-08 19:51:16.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1549): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-08 19:51:16.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1549): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
12-08 19:51:16.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3597)
12-08 19:51:16.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
12-08 19:51:16.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
12-08 19:51:16.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
12-08 19:51:16.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-08 19:51:16.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-08 19:51:16.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-08 19:51:16.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-08 19:51:16.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-08 19:51:16.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-08 19:51:16.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-08 19:51:16.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-08 19:51:16.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1549): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-08 19:51:16.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-08 19:51:16.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-08 19:51:16.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3592)
12-08 19:51:16.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     ... 11 more
12-08 19:51:16.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1549): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
12-08 19:51:16.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:4463)
12-08 19:51:16.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at nc.prog1415.Networking.isWirelessConnected(Networking.java:14)
12-08 19:51:16.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at nc.prog1415.Main.hotshotBtns(Main.java:109)
12-08 19:51:16.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     ... 14 more
```

Comment: Post your logcat errors. I'd guess that `netwrk.wireless()` is null when the device doesn't have a WiFi connection, you should check against this.

Comment: Ive edited my question with the errors it throws

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the LogCat:

> System services not available to Activities before `onCreate()`

This error is rather self-explanatory, so change your code to this:

```
ConnectivityManager cm; 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    cm = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    ...
}
```

---

**Addition**
Your Networking extends Main, which I assume is an Activity. Since you don't want a full Activity for what you are doing you should take a different tactic. You should pass Networking a Context in your constructor instead:

```
public class Networking {
    Context context;

    public Networking(Context con) {
        context = con;
    }

    public boolean isWirelessConnected()
    {
        cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); 
        NetworkInfo mwifi = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        if(mwifi == null)
            return false;
        else 
            return mwifi.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }

    // etc
}
```

Notice that I switched to `context.getSystemService()` you'll need to do this while creating your dialog as well.

Now change the way you use this method:

```
Networking netwrk = new Networking(this);
if(netwrk.isWirelessConnected())
```

Comment: So within the Networking class I should be overriding the onCreate that is used by the main class? Or should I be scrapping the networking class completely and doing it like this all in the main?

Comment: What class does Networking extend? Post some of your Networking class.

Comment: I've edited the reply with my entire networking class, Please note that within my main class I have several methods outside the oncreate including the one that invokes the networking class for this functionality.

Comment: Thanks my friend The context fix fixed my issue.

Comment: Just out of curiosity if I change my message dialog to the contex.getSystemService should that fix the same issue I have with that?

Comment: Yes, `getSysmteService()` is a member of the Context class and `new AlertDialog(context)` will work too.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely `netwrk.wireless()` is returning null and causing a `NullPointerException`.

I would change your `wireless()` method to be `isWirelessConnected()` as follows

```
public boolean isWirelessConnected() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); 
       NetworkInfo mwifi = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

    if ( mwifi == null )
        return false;
    else
        return mwifi.isConnected();
}
```

Then in the main class, simply do

```
Networking netwrk = new Networking();
if( netwrk.isWirelessConnected() ) {
    Intent brwoserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.own3d.tv/HotshotGG"));
    startActivity(brwoserIntent); 
}
```

Comment: Sadly, that doesn't fix the issue of the program completely stopping

Comment: You'll need to post the logcat output with the error when it closes then.